# Logging route parameter/request variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Currently I'm logging errors in my `app/global.php` with:

```
Log::error($exception . ' - ' . Request::url());
```

For the most part the stack trace is enough to find an fix issues however there are times where I need to know what request variables (post/get) or route parameters are being sent. What is the proper way of retrieving these variables so I can log them for debugging?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help some people out here is the full debug

```
Log::error($exception . ' - ' . Request::url());
Log::warning('[DEBUG] [Input] ' . implode(' / ', Request::all()));
if(Route::current())
    Log::warning('[DEBUG] [Route] ' . Route::current()->uri() . ' - ' . implode(' / ', Route::current()->parameters()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all input variables using the `Request` facade as well.

**Request input including files**

```
Request::all();
```

**Request input without files**

```
Request::input();
```

Comment: Thanks that is half the answer that I already had but I figured out that logs are a single line (duh) so I needed an `implode()`